# Jenkins: import external package from Jenkinsfile using declarative syntax

Tags: json, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I had a groovy code which contains "`import groovy.json.JsonSlurper`".

I have spent a day testing and I don't know how to load external libraries using declarative syntax.

This is my code:

```
pipeline {

agent any

import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

        stages {

                stage("test") {

                        steps {
                         }
                }
        }
}
```

I have read the jenkins documentation, and I have tried to use the next but without success:

@Grab('groovy.json.JsonSlurper')
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

both import and @Grab are not recognized. Some idea?

Thanks!

Comment: What if you do not use the line `@Grab(..)`?

Comment: Firstly i was using import only but without success so i tried @Grab with the same result

Comment: This question is still interesting. Have you found a Solution? Would be very helpful.

Comment: The @Grab scope and the import have to be at the beginning of the code, not in the pipeline brackets.

Answer (score 1):

What @Daniel Majano says is true about the `import` syntax, but the `@Grab` syntax I found holds differences of behavior between a `Pipeline script` maintained directly in Jenkins vs `Pipeline script from SCM`.

When I placed a Grab command in the Pipeline script for a tester pipeline job I found that it didn't make any difference whether the Grab command was there or if it was commented out.

[image: Pipeline script snippet]

However when used from a `Pipeline script from SCM` it would throw the following exception...

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: No suitable ClassLoader found for grab
```

I removed it from the SCM script and everything worked out in the end.

---

### Additional Background

I'm not sure why the grab was choking in the SCM version, but there's definitely some working parts to the groovy editor because if you define a partial grab command it will give you some validation errors pointing to the broken line as you see in the red X box below, with the error `The missing attribute "module" is required in @Grab annotations`:

[image: groovy Grab syntax validator]
Therefore the script validator is aware of the Grab annotation as it calls it and that it has both a group and module attribute. I'm using the so called [shorthand notation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/grape.html#_add_a_dependency) in this example.